# Check if a Column Exists in a RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

This is not finding the column. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
if (((RadGrid)sender).Columns.Contains("ClaimNumber"))
    do this...
else
    do this...
```

I checked the Columns Collection of the grid and I can see the column there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `FindByUniqueNameSafe` method:

```
GridColumn col = RadRadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueNameSafe("ColumnName");
if (col != null)
{
    //column exists
}
```

You could also use LINQ:

```
if (RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Cast<GridColumn>().Count(x => x.UniqueName == "Column1") > 0)
```